# Confusion about the definition of a "loop" in a topological space

Tags: general-topology, definition

A continuous map $f:[0,1] \to X$ is called a *path* and if $f(0)=f(1)$ then it is called a *loop*.

But any loop looks like a circle which is not a function as it is not well defined.  How did it possible?  Can someone explain me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean it's not a function? It is well defined -- you just defined it!

Comment: If $f$ is not injective, the associated loop may not look like a circle: for example the eight figure is a loop.

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing things.

You are correct that there is no function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ such that the points $(x,f(x))$ (over any set of $x$)  describe a circle.

However, you can define a function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ whose locus defines a circle, to wit, $g(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$.

Answer (score 0):

A loop is terminology for a special class of functions $f:[0,1]\to X$, namely those continuous functions such that $f(0)=f(1)$. Generally, if we have a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to X$, then $f$ is called a path. A generalization of the idea of a parametric function, we call such a function a path because as $t$ goes from $0$ to $1$, $f(t)$ traces the "curve" starting at $f(0)$, following along $f([0,1])$, and ending at $f(1)$. In the special case that $f(0)=f(1)$, the path ends where it began, which is what you'd expect from something called a "loop."